# Do I have to rewind a file pointer after using fgetc?

Tags: c

When I read a File with fgetc like this:

```
FILE* ptr;
char ch;


ptr = fopen("test.txt", "r");

if (NULL == ptr) {
    printf("file can't be opened \n");
}


do {
    ch = fgetc(ptr);
    printf("%c", ch);

    // Checking if character is not EOF.
    // If it is EOF stop eading.
} while (ch != EOF);

// Closing the file
fclose(ptr);
return 0;
```

And I now want to continue reading from the File pointer `fptr` from the beginning of the file.

Should I use `rewind(fptr);` now in order to rewind back to the state of the beginning of the file?

Comment: `char ch;` ==> `int ch;`

Comment: [`rewind()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rewind.html) clears the error indicator for the stream. If you want to use that indicator, use it before rewinding.

Comment: also, you will print the EOF pseudo-character this way. You need to check for EOF before printf!

Comment: On what operating system and with what compiler?

Comment: @EricPostpischil "And I now want to continue reading from the File pointer `fptr` from the beginning of the file."

Answer (score 0):

As commented, `ch` should be an `int`, not a  `char`.

Read the [n1570](https://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) draft standard or better. See [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) website.

<sup>(In some implementations, a `char` is between 0 and 255, and `EOF` is -1; in other implementations, a `char` is between -128 and 127, and `EOF` is something outside of that. On some weird microcontrollers, a `char` could have 16 or 32 bits. On old computers, `char` had 7 or 9 bits...).</sup>

> Should I use `rewind(fptr);` now in order to rewind back to the state of the beginning of the file?

Yes, but before `fclose(fptr)` (after calling it successfully you should no more use `fptr`, unless you do some `fptr = fopen(`...`)` again or reassign *cleverly* `fptr`)

And [rewind](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/rewind.3.html) can fail (e.g. on `/proc/self/maps` on Linux systems; see [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and [symlink(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/symlink.2.html) ..; or on [tty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal)-s or [serial ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_port)). You need to test it.

Use [perror(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) or [errno(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html)

PS. With [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compile using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` ; In 2022 use [UTF8 everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/) with libraries like [libunistring](https://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/) or Glib from [GTK](https://gtk.org/).

Comment: So I should only use rewind once, before `fclose`? So if right after my example I execute the exact same code - wouldn't it start reading chars from EOF?

Comment: You could use `rewind` a thousand times. I don't believe you should do so.

Comment: The question is if I have to rewind in order to use File pointer from the beginning after using `fgetc`. Your answer is essentialy "yes, but before fclose". But when I call `fclose` I won't be able to use that same File pointer again...

Comment: @stht55: How does telling you that `rewind` can only work before `fclose` negate the fact that this answer tells you that, to reread the file from the beginning with the same file pointer, you must use `rewind` (or equivalent call such as `fseek` with appropriate arguments)?

Comment: On what systems is the range of `char` -128..+127 (signed) and EOF is outside of that range?  On most Linux Intel systems, `char` is signed but EOF is still `-1`, for example.

Comment: I think that my Powerbook G4 (in 2003?) had signed `char`s, at least with some Linux distribution on it. And I recall that some C interpreter coded in Common Lisp has 32 bits `char`s